# Exposing the indexer / default property via COM Interop

Tags: c#, collections, asp-classic, vbscript, com-interop

I am attempting to write a component in C# to be consumed by classic ASP that allows me to access the indexer of the component (aka default property).

For example:
C# component:

```
public class MyCollection {
    public string this[string key] {
        get { /* return the value associated with key */ }
    }

    public void Add(string key, string value) {
        /* add a new element */
    }
}
```

ASP consumer:

```
Dim collection
Set collection = Server.CreateObject("MyCollection ")
Call collection.Add("key", "value")
Response.Write(collection("key")) ' should print "value"
```

Is there an attribute I need to set, do I need to implement an interface or do I need to do something else? Or this not possible via COM Interop?

The purpose is that I am attempting to create test doubles for some of the built-in ASP objects such as Request, which make use of collections using these default properties (such as `Request.QueryString("key")`). Alternative suggestions are welcome.

Update: I asked a follow-up question: [Why is the indexer on my .NET component not always accessible from VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317759/why-is-the-indexer-on-my-net-component-not-always-accessible-from-vbscript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the DispId attribute of the property to be 0, as described here in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dispidattribute(VS.71).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, this got it working but not on this[string key]. I had to apply DispId to another property before it worked.

Comment: Oops, it appears applying DispId to the indexer, e.g. this[string key], does work if it's not overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rob Walker's tip, I got it working by adding the following method and attribute to MyCollection:

```
[DispId(0)]
public string Item(string key) {
    return this[key];
}
```

Edit: See [this better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311946/3195477) which uses an indexer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better solution that uses an indexer rather than an `Item` method:

```
public class MyCollection {
    private NameValueCollection _collection;

    [DispId(0)]
    public string this[string name] {
        get { return _collection[name]; }
        set { _collection[name] = value; }
    }
}
```

It can be used from ASP like:

```
Dim collection
Set collection = Server.CreateObject("MyCollection")
collection("key") = "value"
Response.Write(collection("key")) ' should print "value"
```

Note: I could not get this to work earlier because I had overloaded the indexer, `this[string name]`, with `this[int index]`.