# C# Objects in VBScript

Tags: c#, dll, vbscript

I have re-written an existing VB6 DLL into C#. However, the DLL is called from existing VBScript so needs to be compatible. The DLL has a collection object which is a collection of other objects from the DLL.

So, I basically have a *ParentObject* (which isn't a collection) that has a number of properties. One of these is a *CollectionObject* which is a custom class that implements ArrayList thus:

```
    public class CollectionObjects : ArrayList
    {
        public new CollectionObject this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return (CollectionObject)base[index];
            }
        }
    }
```

In my VBscript I can successfully do For Each loops around the CollectionObjects like this

```
for each listItem in parentObject.CollectionObjects
    msgbox listItem.FullName
next
```

However if I try to access items in the collection directly, I get an error

```
msgbox parentObject.CollectionObjects(0).FullName
```

This gives the error 'Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: parentObject.CollectionObjects'

If I use the Item property it works correctly, and it also works if I assign the collection object to another variable first

```
'  all these work
msgbox parentObject.CollectionObjects.Item(0).FullName
set list = parentObject.CollectionObjects
msgbox list(0).FullName
```

I have a large number of VBScripts that reference the DLL so going through all of them is not really practical. I'm hoping I'm missing an implementation of something somewhere. It is strange that not using the Item property works when you have a variable that is the CollectionObjects collection, but you need it when trying to reference it off another object.

Does anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: Side note: Why do you implement `ArrayList`? It is a very dated type? Does it have to do with COM visibility or backwards compatibility with legacy code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the indexer on my .NET component not always accessible from VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317759/why-is-the-indexer-on-my-net-component-not-always-accessible-from-vbscript)

Comment: Yes @Igor , the vbscript is all legacy code so it needs to be backward compatible. The DLL i'm replacing had a private collection as part of the CollectionObjects object, and implemented the Add, Remove and such like explicitly. I am trying to avoid having to write them explicitly

Comment: My question was more along the lines of why use `ArrayList` instead of a generic `List<T>` which offers many of the same methods (add, remove, etc) but offers type safety and is preferred over `ArrayList`. I am just not sure if there are any COM specific issues with `List<T>` (It has been a while since I worked with COM and .NET).

Comment: I've been unable to get the for each working when it has been based on a List<T>. I found a number of articles indicating it was better to use ArrayList, but I'm open to anything as long as I don't have to go through approx 4000 scripts to check for problems...

Comment: You are just battling a syntax ambiguity.  Caused by both VB and COM allowing indexed properties.  Something that the C# language clamped down heavily and outright forbade, a class can only have one indexed property and it is indexed with [square brackets].  What you *meant* was parentObject.CollectionObjects()(0).FullName.  In other words, obtain the property value and apply (0) to the default property of the returned object.  What the VBScript interpreter sees is "apply (0) to the property".  Kaboom, CollectionObject is not an indexed property.  You'll have to make it a method instead.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant that makes sense. I was beginning to think it was something to do with the declaration. Using it as a method might be problematic because of the instances of 'for each' in the vbscripts. I guess I'll just have to see how many instances of each usage.