# Default Property for dotNet Interop Usercontrol

Tags: vb.net, vb6, com-interop

I need to set the default property of a dotNet Control used by an VB6 Application.

```
<ComClass(myControl.ClassId, myControl.InterfaceId, myControl.EventsId)> _
<DefaultProperty("NewProperty")> _
Public Class myControl

    Public Const ClassId As String = "86252de2-ca87-4468-adbe-ad7c47747759"
    Public Const InterfaceId As String = "c1cbf1a1-24bb-46c3-88a4-813eb4917845"
    Public Const EventsId As String = "954ed890-011c-4908-ab33-610159fe6eb1"

    Private newPropertyValue As String
    Public Property NewProperty() As String
        Get
            Return newPropertyValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            newPropertyValue = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

The DefualtProperty Attribute does not do the trick.

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299251/exposing-the-indexer-default-property-via-com-interop) that manually setting the DispId to Zero should do the trick. But if I do this:

```
<DispId(0)> Public Property NewProperty() As String
```

Visual Basic kindly informs me that the DispId Zero is reserved for the DefaultProperty. Yeah. I know that. I want that. But how?

Edit:

```
Default Public Property NewProperty(ByVal foo As Integer) As String
```

Does work as the property now shows up as the default property in VB6. But this will not solve my problem, because there is code which I can't change, which will do something like this:

```
aStringVariable = myUserControlInstance
```

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7bfkxc1(VS.71).aspx) has some information about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because there is code which I can't
>   change

If that the case then you need to create a wrapper class around the original .NET Class and export that as the control used by VB6. Then you can mark the default property as using the default keyword.

Comment: Has the wrapper to be a VB6 user control? Or can I do some magic on the dotNet side?

Comment: Your choice. The wrapper will pretty much duplicate the original control except make the default property work the way you want. If you want to use a default property with no parameters then you will need to definitely use the vb6 user control

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I will accept this answer in a few days, if nobody else answers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way but to create a wrapper in VB6 to mimic the default property behavior of VB6.  I have had to create several interop user controls and this was the main reason we had to wrap a .Net interop control again in VB6 (to avoid a lot of code change and huge testing effort).