# C# collection to Classic ASP

Tags: c#, com, collections, asp-classic

I am having trouble exposing a C# collection to Classic ASP.
I've tried to use IEnumerable and Array. but I get the "`object not a collection`" error.

my method looks like:

```
public IEnumerable<MyObj> GetMyObj() { ... }
```

and on the Classic ASP side:

```
Dim obj, x 
Set obj = Server.CreateObject("Namespace.class")

For Each x in obj.GetMyObj
...
```

So how can I pass a collection to Classic ASP?

### UPDATE:

may be this is a progress, the solution I found was to use a new class that inherits `IEnumerable` instead of using `IEnumerable<MyObj>`:

```
public class MyEnumerable : IEnumerable
{
   private IEnumerable<MyObj> _myObj;

   .
   .
   .

    [DispId(-4)]
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
      _myObj.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

But now when I try to **access a property** of `MyObj` I get an error: `Object required`.

Any idea?

Comment: Not sure, but is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299251/exposing-the-indexer-default-property-via-com-interop the solution to your problem?

Comment: how are you referencing the C# project from Classic ASP

Comment: You should show us as much of the code as possible (including attributes) for both the collection and the object in the collection.  The problem revolves around **COM Interop**, so searching for that could give you the answers you need.

Comment: Thats really all the code. I've got no other attributes, and I've just got another method that loads the `MyEnumerable` and `MyObj` has some properties. what attributes should I have?

Comment: In order to solve the "Object required" error, the object you return with the GetEnumerator() should have the [ComVisible(true)] attribute. That will solve this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you found the answer; Classic ASP with VB does not have generics built into it. So, you try to pass an `IEnumerable<MyObj>` to ASP and it comes out as a nightmarish mashup name which classic ASP has no clue how to work with.

The solution is to pass a non-generic IEnumerable. The problem then is that the sequence is treated as containing basic Object instances. You must revert to the pre-2.0 methods of casting objects you get out of a list. In VB this isn't difficult; just explicitly specify the element type and VB will implicitly cast for you while iterating through the For Each:

```
Dim obj, x 
Set obj = Server.CreateObject("Namespace.class")

For Each x As MyObj in obj.GetMyObj //casts each element in turn
   ...
```

Comment: And my problem, the answer to which was only implied in this answer was that the object being returned (or its base) MUST be `ComVisible`, otherwise VB won't know how to talk to it and raises "Object required"

Answer (score 0):

I know this may sound bizarre but I had a similar issue and solved it by wrapping collection with brackets

```
For Each x in (obj).GetMyObj
```

Don't know why this would make any difference but it worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

If you get an `Object required` error try this:

```
For Each key in obj.GetMyObj
    Set x = obj.GetMyObj(key)
    Response.Write x.YOURPROPERTY
Next
```

Comment: I get a `Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'GetMyObj'` error.

Comment: has this got something to do with generics here? could you redesign your class so that MyObj Derives from IEnumerable?  MyObj : IEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

Reverse-engineering may solve the problem.
Try to pass an ASP classic collection to ASP.NET and then see what the type of object is. Then you can pass that type from ASP.NET to classic ASP instead of a trial-error approach.
If there's no relevant type in ASP.NET then you should do more reverse-engineering and explore the binary data for finding the pattern and writing your own casting method.